# Get a URL from an Action name: Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

In struts 2 there is a struts tag where you can specify an action name and it gives you the url to that action:

```
<s:url action="action_name" />
```

I've been looking for a while now to see if it is possible to do this in an Struts2 Action/Interceptor. I found the class that relates to this struts tag I think (`org.apache.struts2.components.URL`) but can't figure out how to use it.

This is as far as I got but it might not be how to use it (if its possible at all) but any method I call after this just gives me NullPointerExceptions.:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {

    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();

    URL url = new URL(ai.getStack(), request, response);
    url.setAction("login");
    //e.g. url.start(<with stringwriter>);

}
```

Hoping this can be done as it would save a lot of troube!

Thanks.

### EDIT

```
URL url = new URL(invocation.getStack(), request, response);
url.setActionMapper(new DefaultActionMapper());

String redirectUrl = url.getUrlProvider().determineActionURL("action_name", 
    invocation.getProxy().getNamespace(), invocation.getProxy().getMethod(), 
    request, response, request.getParameterMap(), "http", true, true, false, false);
```

This code does work and gives me a redirect URL but I was wondering if there was a way to get the CURRENT ActionMapper rather than create a new one. I've done a quick google but can't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is the method in the component class inside struts2 which is creating action URL

```
protected String determineActionURL(String action, String namespace, String method, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Map parameters, String scheme, 
            boolean includeContext, boolean encodeResult, boolean forceAddSchemeHostAndPort, boolean escapeAmp)
    {
        String finalAction = findString(action);
        String finalMethod = method == null ? null : findString(method);
        String finalNamespace = determineNamespace(namespace, getStack(), req);
        ActionMapping mapping = new ActionMapping(finalAction, finalNamespace, finalMethod, parameters);
        String uri = actionMapper.getUriFromActionMapping(mapping);
        return UrlHelper.buildUrl(uri, req, res, parameters, scheme, includeContext, encodeResult, forceAddSchemeHostAndPort, escapeAmp);
    }
```

now the question is how we can get various values for this

```
action=invocation.getAction();
namespace=invocation.getProxy().getNamespace();
methos= invocation.getProxy().getMethod();
```

similar other values can be find out from ActionIvocation
This is just an idea and i have not applied it myself.Hope it might help you.

Comment: Thanks this really helped! I've edited my question above with something extra I hope you can help with :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I get the CURRENT ActionMapper rather than create a new one:

```
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Namespace;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Inject;

@Namespace("MyNamespace")
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private ActionMapper actionMapper;
    private UrlHelper urlHelper;

    @Inject
    public void setActionMapper(ActionMapper mapper) {
        this.actionMapper = mapper;
    }

    @Inject
    public void setUrlHelper(UrlHelper urlHelper) {
        this.urlHelper = urlHelper;
    }

    private String getAbsoluteUrl(String actionName, String namespace) {
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
        ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext();
        ActionInvocation invocation = context.getActionInvocation();

        URL url = new URL(invocation.getStack(), request, response);
        url.setActionMapper(actionMapper);
        url.setUrlHelper(urlHelper);

        return url.getUrlProvider().determineActionURL( //
            actionName, //
            namespace, //
            "" , /* Method name */
            request, response, //
            request.getParameterMap(), "http", //
            true, true, true, false);
    }

    // ...
}
```