# Redirecting all the request followed by some some name to single page

Tags: struts2

If any user request for the page such as /q/abc1 and /q/abc2 and so on. I want to redirect all the request that is followed by q to a single page.

Suppose whenever user requests with www.mysite.com/q/abc1 or www.mysite.com/q/abc2, I want to redirect all the requests followed by q to a single page e.g. handler.jsp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191144/get-a-url-from-an-action-name-struts-2 hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... How about `package` with `namespace="/q"` and default action 
`<default-action-ref name="someAction"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use filter and filter out the request before fwd to struts 2 framework ( FilterDispatcher)

```
public class SampleServletFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            String requestURI = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
            if(requestURI.contains("/q/")) {
               // redirect to handler.jsp
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }     

       }    
   }
```

As it is tricky to handle this scenario with struts2 interceptors.